# Locate users in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Is there a way to locate users that are no longer with a company but that are still part of workflows in SharePoint?

I need to be able to remove the user(s) that are no longer with the company but unsure how to do this without having to go through every single workflow. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove them from workflows and the user account is defined in the workflow, rather than in a group the account is in is defined in the workflow, I'm pretty sure you have to visit each workflow and explicitly remove them from it.  If you are just looking to remove the user from the site collection or remove all permissions, open the user from a group or from the site collection users group (https://"replace with site collection URL"/_layouts/"replace with SharePoint hive number"/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0) and inside their profile will be a delete from site collection option.  Doing that will remove their permissions from the site collection wherever they may be, but might make workflows fail if they are a direct participant as defined above, so I'd check that first.

Comment: Thanks so much for this reply and I will use this as a reference moving forward. I will manually check or wait until the issue arises again to review that specific WF and remove the username. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a single user from the workflow, then I am afraid you have to manually modify the workflow. If it is in the group, you only need to delete the user in the group.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have notified the manager if that specific user's name comes up in any other workflows to inform me so I can remove it. Thanks for all your time!